# Unicode char in html page

Tags: unicode, char, arrows

in order to create a map with SellOut trend i'm searching a native unicode green arrow to paste in my chart. Anyone has an idea in order to do this?!

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes, because i need to find some "programming way" to do this